# dynamic filter with django + ajax + display in templates

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I am new to django and js, please, i need help. So, i want to filter model objects without page reload. I form the filter conditions and send to the server via ajax something like this:
(Please do not scold for the code, I'm just trying to understand the essence...)

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url,
    data: { 
        'output': output_json,
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
            console.log(success);
            data.map(smth =>{
            content_container.innerHTML = `${ smth.smth }
                                           {% for ${el} in ${ smth.smth.all } %}
                                              ${ el.smth }
                                           {% endfor %}`
           })
           },
           error: function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                },  
            });
        });
</script>
```

(from the server I receive data in json format)
document.getElementById(#smth).innerhtml = `....` so here is my question:
if i use in innerhtml something like this ${ smth.smth1} - it's not a problem, but if i want to use 'for loop' over related objects : {% for el in smth.smth2.all %} and then use el.smth, JS don't understand me... So how i can loop through the elements from the received data in innerhtml. I will be glad for any hint and help.

Comment: If someone understands what I want ))) I can show the code in more detail

Comment: Please try to improve your question by adding minimal but reproducible code, and the error message that you get. [ask]